# Unable to authenticate using MSAL for iOS Swift4.2

Tags: ios, swift, azure-ad-msal, swift4.2

I'm not able to execute MSAL SDK. I'm getting below mentioned issue...I've gone through many StackOverflow questions but still unable to resolve this issue.

**Issue :**

```
qwerty[66144:4049892] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "msauthv2://broker" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
qwerty[66144:4052892] Failed to query AuthBrokerAgent Task <49DC4AA3-FAC7-4268-94DA-41FE68FD584F>.<1>
qwerty[66144:4052892] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htsx;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    srvr = "intpxy1.ind.mobi";
    sync = syna;
}
qwerty[66144:4052492] Failed to get applicable proxy auth Task <49DC4AA3-FAC7-4268-94DA-41FE68FD584F>.<1>
qwerty[66144:4050495] Task <49DC4AA3-FAC7-4268-94DA-41FE68FD584F>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: 311 [4:-2097])
qwerty[66144:4052491] Task <49DC4AA3-FAC7-4268-94DA-41FE68FD584F>.<1> finished with error - code: 311
App error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=311 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2097, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
qwerty[66144:4052495] Received XPC error Connection interrupted for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery
qwerty[66144:4052495] Received XPC error Connection invalid for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery
```

My System Configuration :

- Mac OS    : macOS High Sierra
- XCode Ver : Version 10.1 (10B61)

Please help me.

Comment: i am not sure what is the issue, but please check kClientID, kAuthority is given correctly, also please update plist with
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>msauth.[BUNDLE_ID]</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

Comment: please tell us what all things you have implemented

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all the following things are in place:
kClientID, kAuthority,LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Also ensure you have an active Microsoft account. I recently integrated Microsoft login as below.

```
func initMSAL() throws {
        guard let authorityURL = URL(string: kAuthority) else {
            return
        }
        let authority = try MSALAADAuthority(url: authorityURL)
        let msalConfiguration = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId:kClientID, redirectUri: nil, authority: authority)
        self.applicationContext = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: msalConfiguration)
    }


    func loginUser(completion:@escaping((Bool) -> Void)) {
        guard let applicationContext = self.applicationContext else { return }
        let parameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters.init(scopes: kScopes, webviewParameters: MSALWebviewParameters(parentViewController: (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController)!))
        parameters.promptType = .selectAccount
        applicationContext.acquireToken(with: parameters) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Could not acquire token: \(error)")
                return
            }

            guard let result = result else {
                print("Could not acquire token: No result returned")
                return
            }
            print("Access Token is:", result.accessToken)
            
            completion(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've set clientID, kScopes, redirectUri, etc all required properties.

Comment: I created a class for handling all actions related to Microsoft authentication and in its init method I called initMSAL method defined above. loginUser is called when user clicks the login button.

Comment: Also I was able to replicate the above error if I did not add msauth in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. We need to add three values in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array -> msauth, msauthv2, msauthv3

Comment: Yeah, I've added this all required properties in info.plist file.

Comment: May I know on which OS & XCode version did you tried?

Comment: Could you please update me all step-by-step implementation. Because you got it successfully that's why. I chasing this issue quite 2-3 days. Please help.

Comment: Xcode version is 11.2.1
OS: macOS Catalina(10.15.5) 

First I setup an Azure Account.
In info plist I added LSApplicationQueries as described above and in URL types added bundleId of the app with prefix msauth (msauth.com.test.Test) 
In a constants file added ClientId, scopes , graph Endpoint.
And then created a class which has the above two methods and an init method which I described above.When I call loginUser first the init method of the class gets triggered and then the loginUser method gets called.